# PHP Mutliarray Key and Value Print

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$icecream = array (
    "Choco" => array('2 Dollars'),
    "Mango" => array('3 Dollars')
 );
```

print $icecream[0][0];

expected output:
*2 Dollars*

Edit: I have a huge list of icecream sorts and i do want to use a loop to output all the information as a HTML DOM. So I do not want to go through each array value and echo it with the explicit value (i.e. 'Choco', 'Orange', etc...).

I want to use values as keys for the "first array level" ($icecream[0]),

It does output nothing at all. What is my logical flaw with this solution?

Comment: you have to print $icecream["Choco"][0]  (you have key name so you can't access it with position number 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

`echo $icecream['Choco'][0]`

Your problem here is calling the wrong key for the 1st dim

.
.

For your updated question, try this:

```
$ice_k = array_keys($icecream);
echo  $icecream[$ice_k[0]][0];
```

Comment: I edited the question to provide the necessary context. I'm sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @RaheelHasan +1 for sportsmanship, helping two times so user satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the associative array right. You need to use the right key.

```
    echo $icecream['choco'][0];
```

Comment: But what if the first item of the array will change it's name? I can't rely on the explicit value. Can't I use the position of the first array item?

Comment: But how do you which position is what flavour? The most logic thing would be to give them an id that never changes and a name that could change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position but it will be a counter like this:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($icecream As $k=>$v) {
    echo $icecream[$k][0] . ' [' . $counter . ']';
    $counter++;
}
```

and if you want to get only value you can use previous code

```
$ice_k = array_keys($icecream);
$position = 5;
if( isset($ice_k[$position]) ) {
    echo  $icecream[$ice_k[$position]][0];
}
```